# Add 24 hours to getTime() for each 5000 characters

Tags: javascript

I would to make a javascript loop that would return me the date depending on how much characters are in a document.

```
var d = new Date.getTime();
var s = 9349859; //Random number of characters

if(s < 5000){
   d = "Same day";
}else{
   //Do the loop I'm searching
   ....
```

But if I want to make a loop that every 5000 characters that it will add 24 hours to the getTime() var. How ?

Comment: the result is in time tick or in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the number of days and add to the date object

```
var d    = new Date();
var s    = 9349859;
var days = Math.floor( s / 5000 );

d.setDate(d.getDate() + days);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/GB7MD/)

Answer (score 0):

you absolutly want a loop ? cause I'd advise you to simply make a count number of caracters divised by the range you want (500) and add the number of hours required.

so no loops ...

Comment: So like 25000 / 5000 = 5.... 3600*5 = new date ? Something like that ? Would use floo() to round the number of course.

Comment: yop but notice that floor() and round() are not the same. After it depends on what you try to archieve.

Answer (score 0):

What you simply could do is something like this:

```
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}

var d = new Date.getTime();
var s = 9349859; //Random number of characters
var h = 0;

if(s < 5000){
   d = "Same day";
}else{
   while(s >= 5000) {
      h++;
      s -= 5000;
   }

   h = h * 24;

   d = new Date().addHours(h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any loop for this. Simply divide number of characters by 5000 to get the number of days to add. You might want to `floor` (round down) or `ceil` (round up). My example rounds up - therefore adding a day for every 5000 characters or part thereof:

```
var d = new Date();
var s = 9349859; //Random number of characters

var numDays = Math.ceil(s/5000);

var newDate = new Date()
newDate.setDate(d.getDate() + numDays);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/SJV26/